Why have simple function only a finite number of summands?
I have a short question about simple functions which are used to define the Lebesgue-Integral. Is there a special reason, why we only allow a finite number of summands in defining simple functions? Would there be any problem if we change the sum to a series in combination with an infinite partition of the set where the function is defined? Thank you for your help!

You certainly can try defining it that way, but an infinite sum runs into the issue of convergence. Even if, say, you restrict to positive functions to resolve this, you don’t really get anything new from this than just using finite sums.

Btw, if you allow an uncountable number of summands, then a simple function is... just a function.

@freaktish thank you for your answer. But would there be a problem in defining the Lebesgue integral if we allow series instead of only sums?

The point of defining simple functions is that you can define the Lebesgue integral for general measurable functions as a limit or supremum over integrals for simple functions, on which the Lebesgue integral is easy to define. Allowing infinite summands for simple functions defeats that purpose; you have to deal with all the issues of convergence at the start instead of getting it for free (and this would be before LDCT and similar results).

@anomaly Thank you! Do you know an example which would face the problem?

"a finite number is enough" reminds me of the (Alksandrov ?) definition of a compact set in terms of a finite covering issued from an infinite one....

If they had an infinite number of summands they would not be simple,  there would ar limit to contend with when considering the integral of a simple function.

@RobRTex It’s less about specific examples, more just as long as you’re considering an infinite sum of indicator functions, its integral will then be, presumably, an infinite sum, so that already has issues of convergence of infinite sums. If you insist on a specific example, just consider something like, say, $\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty (-1)^n 1_{(n, n + 1]}$. Of course, this would not happen if you only consider positive functions, in which case defining integrals using “finite” simple functions and “infinite” simple functions are the same. It’s just unnecessary to consider infinite sums.

(Though arguably this is more of a convention than anything else. If Lebesgue integrals had been defined using these “infinite” simple functions in the first place, no doubt I would be saying now that doing that is more natural than using finite sums. There are advantages to using finite sums, but I can also see why using infinite sums might be a good idea in some context.)

I thought about it, because I asked myself if I can define the integral for positive measurable functions using an upper integral (instead of the standard lower integral). Doing this with finite partitions for simple functions I get a problem with unbounded functions using only finite partitions for the positive simple functions. So maybe it’s possible to construct the integral equivalently using infite simple functions and upper integrals. Do you know if this is a possible way?

@RobRTex Yes, that is possible. And you’re right in thinking that you need infinite simple functions for that. Any positive function in $L^1$ but not bounded, as you mentioned, will never be dominated by a finite simple function. But it is true that, for any positive function $f$, its integral is the infimum of the integrals of all infinite simple functions larger than or equal to $f$.

(I don’t have any reference for this though. I’m not aware of anyone actually defining integrals this way. Though there is an old book which considers measure theory from the point of view of integrals - that is, integrals are treated as primitive concepts instead of measures - and starts with upper integrals, analogous to outer measures. See https://books.google.com/books/about/Topics_in_the_Theory_of_Lifting.html?id=vTL6CAAAQBAJ .)

Great. Thank you very much for your help. I will have a look into the your suggested book. I think it is interesting because the original construction of the Lebesgue integral by W. H. Young also uses upper and lower integrals in analogy to Darboux. So I came to the idea to ask myself about the equivalence.
